# MongoDB group and find results where value doesn't ocour

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents in my db:

```
{
    id: ObjectId(...),
    value1: 0,
    value2: false
}, {
    id: ObjectId(...),
    value1: 0,
    value2: true
}, {
    id: ObjectId(...),
    value1: 1,
    value2: false
}, {
    id: ObjectId(...),
    value1: 1,
    value2: false
}, {
    id: ObjectId(...),
    value1: 1,
    value2: false
}
```

I want to group all objects by value1 and found those, which don't have a value2=true.

See the objects with value1=0.
You can see that there exists one document with value2=true.

For value1=1 there doesn't exists a document with value2=true.
I want to have all this value1 where I don't have a value2=true.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {'value1': '$value1', 'value2' : '$value2'}, count: {$sum:1}}},
    {$match: {'_id.value2': true, count: {$eq: 0}}}
])
```

I tried this, but this wouldn't find anything.
Because I filtered out the true values. So there is nothing to count.

I hope you understand me and can help me.

**Edit 1 - My desired result:**
I want to get something like that:

```
{
    value1: 0,
    count: 1   // value1=0 has exactly 1 document with value2=true
}, {
    value1: 1, // <-- Im just interested in this values which has the count of 0
    count: 0   // <-- value1=1 has NO documents with value2=true
}
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to say but if you publish your desired result, it will be easier to suggest you a solution.

Comment: What about documents with multiple `value2= true` entries for a specific `value1` ? Do you want that too ?

Comment: They can also be a part of the result, but all I need is them with **no** value2=true documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. This will keep all the groups where `values2` has atleast one true value or all the `values2` are false

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$value1",
        values2: {
            $push: "$value2"
        }
    }
}, {
    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $or: [{
                    $anyElementTrue: ["$values2"]
                }, {
                    $setEquals: ["$values2", [false]]
                }]
            },
            then: "$$KEEP",
            else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: I changed the `if` to the following: `if: { $setEquals: ["$values2", [false]] }` now I get only them with all values are false. That's a great solution. I didn't know this commands `redact` before. Thank you

Comment: Awesome that's what I thought, but wasn't entirely sure to take it off.